# Rails devise sign up, sign in not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails and just tried to setup user sign up, sign through devise but none of the sign up and sign in are working, when I click on sign up the page just keeps unchanged, it does not even show error messages.

I just added this in my application.html.erb file for errors

```
<%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  <%- end -%>
```

Console messages

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2022-02-18 21:23:31 +0530
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"ry201@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "ry201@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 462)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 93)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.2ms | Allocations: 2047)
  Rendered home/_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 128)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 13.5ms | Allocations: 4452)
Completed 200 OK in 216ms (Views: 15.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms | Allocations: 10722)
```

Comment: can you please include the devise code and other pieces required to reproduce a 'minimum viable example'.

Comment: Form code and an example of the params getting sent would be useful

Comment: added the console message

Comment: It isn't saving because the user already exists `User Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "ry201@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction` <- So it then rolls back the transaction.  so the user is in the DB, if you are having an issue with sign in you will need to likely open another question and I would also make sure to post the params in there.